# Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error

Tags: debugging, apport

I will show here what I got with error tracker

```
Error reports sent from this system

Occurred    Received    Problem Type    Program
2017-02-21 08:02    2017-02-21 09:02 UTC    Crash   boinc-client
2017-02-20 07:02    2017-02-21 08:02 UTC    Crash   boinc-client
2017-02-16 08:02    2017-02-17 08:02 UTC    Crash   boinc-client
2017-02-13 18:02    2017-02-13 18:02 UTC    Crash   google-chrome-stable
2017-02-13 07:02    2017-02-13 07:02 UTC    Crash   boinc-client
2017-02-09 08:02    2017-02-10 08:02 UTC    Crash   unattended-upgrades
2017-02-10 08:02    2017-02-10 08:02 UTC    Crash   /usr/bin/boinc
2017-02-07 13:02    2017-02-07 13:02 UTC    Crash   boinc-client
2017-02-01 08:02    2017-02-01 08:02 UTC    Crash   /usr/bin/boinc
2017-01-25 08:01    2017-01-30 08:01 UTC    Crash   boinc-client
2016-12-21 13:12    2016-12-21 16:12 UTC    Crash   evince
2016-10-26 10:10    2016-10-27 08:10 UTC    Package matlab-support
2015-01-26 16:01    2015-01-26 16:01 UTC    Crash   google-chrome-stable
2015-01-22 17:01    2015-01-22 18:01 UTC    Crash   google-chrome-stable
2015-01-21 16:01    2015-01-21 16:01 UTC    Crash   /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk
2015-01-19 17:01    2015-01-19 17:01 UTC    Crash   google-chrome-stable
2015-01-19 14:01    2015-01-19 14:01 UTC    Crash   gnome-disk-utility
```

How should I solve this?

Answer (score -2):

Those are error-reports send to the developers of Ubuntu. Just wait until there comes an update. Run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

To check for and install updates.